# HtmlToOpenXml - HTML to Docx Conversion -

Tags: openxml

How to enable page numbers while converting HTML to Docx using HtmlToOpenXML API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe [HtmlToOpenXML](http://notesforhtml2openxml.codeplex.com/) is dependent on the [OpenXml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124). In this case because HtmlToOpenXML does not support page numbers, you can use the SDK to add page numbers directly.

You can find out how to do this by generating the code required to create a simple word document with page numbers using the SDK's OpenXml Productivity Tool's [Reflect Code](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA&feature=player_detailpage#t=190s) feature.

I have done this myself but it generates a lot of code so I won't post it here. It's very easy to do though.